# UITabBar Button Center Vertical Alignment Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: Screen Shot]

The screenshot is taken from an earlier version of iOS device.In which show `UITabBar` button are not in center alignment.

Below you can check my current tabbar

[image: Screen Shot]

This is my **UITabBar** button add through Main. StoryBoard.

[image]

How to set all **UITabBar** button in vertical center alignment ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController (ESTabBar) I have used it and does fairly nice job and has APIs similar to `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 5):

You also set image insect through Main.StoryBoard:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this for every `UITabBarItem` in your tabBar. This will make your image vertically center.

```
tabOne.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5,left: 0,bottom: -5,right: 0)
```

Updated with example:

```
    let nvOneViewController = MYRNavigationController()
    let tabOne = MYRHomeViewController()
    let tabOneBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "icnHome"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "icnHomeOn"))
    tabOne.tabBarItem = tabOneBarItem
    tabOne.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5,left: 0,bottom: -5,right: 0)
    nvOneViewController.setViewControllers([tabOne], animated: false)
```

Comment: `tabOne` is the `viewController`

Comment: @ShamDhiman check the updated answer, i have added an example

Comment: Ya sure but your code is not give me output 
i am using Custom tabbar class
and custom navigation class when i am trying to use your code they give me no output.

Comment: @ShamDhiman Pls add your code for `UITabBarItem`, I can help u out !

Comment: I am using StoryBoard to add uitabbarItem

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 13 the icons seem to be vertically centred without any custom code. Prior to iOS 13 I had to add the image insets as mentioned by @Vicky_Vignesh